# Drop down menu variable divs show on page load

Tags: html

Just need a little help on something I haven't been able to find the answer to. I have a drop down menu in HTML that is supposed to display a div with an image associated when a drop down selection is made. The problem is that currently, it will load every div when the page opens and will only hide the divs when a selection is made. I would like nothing shown until the actual selection is made if that makes sense. Here is what I have so far (simplified for the problem's sake):

```
<select onchange="toggle_form_element(this)" name="parts" id="parts">
  <option value="-">Please choose an image</option>
  <option value="0">img 1</option>
  <option value="1">img 2</option>
  <option value="2">img 3</option>
</select>
<span id="dropdown">
  <div id="img1">image 1.jpg</div>
  <div id="img2">image 2.jpg</div>
  <div id="img3">image 3.jpg</div>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggle_form_element(select) {
    var divSelect = select.value;
    var elements = dropdown.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (i == divSelect) {
          elements[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
          elements[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your styles

```
<style>
#dropdown .image
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Then add a class to your elements:

```
<div id="img1" class="image">image 1.jpg</div>
<div id="img2" class="image">image 2.jpg</div>
<div id="img3" class="image">image 3.jpg</div>
```

So, at the beginning images will be hidden by CSS.

After making a choice in your select, your JS will make one of them shown.

Comment: Beat me to it.  You could avoid adding a class by using `#dropdown div` instead.

Comment: I agree, but it was simplified example of the code.
If there are other divs in original code, you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: Sorry! I should've been a bit more clear, Valdimir is right, the code is simplified. There will be more than just an image showing; there will be a list and text underneath as well. I just simplified things for the sake of the question. Although your recommendation still works perfectly if I rename the class. Thank you so much for your help!